# Why i can't ping to another device in local network

Tags: networking, router, ping

I have router Huawei HG8245A. I look at DHCP information, it's looking good.
It show list like this :

[image]

And my next step, I use Zenmap to check all ip which connected to my device. It show like this.

[image]

In this case, it's looked suspicious. So i do some step again. I ping another device that isn't listed in zenmap, it gives this reply.

[image]

Why it happens in my local network? I really don't have any idea for this case.

Note : 192.168.0.122 is my device IP.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the firewall? It look like to be mobile device and it might block ping packet?

[Cant ping Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598334/cant-ping-android-device)

Solution with "nmap" there :

sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24 or sudo nmap -sP 10.0.0.1/24

Comment: In my example, i just ping an android device. But in fact my real target is a laptop which connected to wifi router. I have check my firewall and i off the firewall both of them (Firewall in my device and target device). And the same situation is still happened.

Answer (score 0):

Your PC ICMP protocol disabled. You can give permission with a new rule from

For Windows:

Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings > Inbound Rule > Create New Rule > Custom > All Programs > Select ICMP Protocol and next.

Now, you can get ping from other network devices.